# Kana tag synonyms for the particle tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I started to make some new tags for particles just so they could then be made synonyms of the existing ASCII tags.

For example we have [particle-wa](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-wa) and I made [は](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%e3%81%af).

I didn't realize at the time that I don't actually have sufficient reputation or "points" in the tags to suggest the synonyms myself.

Would a moderator like to make these synonyms?

Or would a user with enough "points" like to begin the synonym voting procedure by suggesting them?

Or if you think it's a terrible idea with no possible merit, here's the place to dissent (-;

Answer (score 4):

I made synonyms for the current set of particle tags:

[か](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%e3%81%8b)　 → 　[particle-ka](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-ka)
　[から](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89) → 　[particle-kara](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-kara)
　[が](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%e3%81%8c) 　→ 　[particle-ga](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-ga)
　[って](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6) → 　[particle-tte](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-tte)
　[で](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%e3%81%a7) 　→ 　[particle-de](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-de)
　[と](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%e3%81%a8) 　→　 [particle-to](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-to)
　[な](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%e3%81%aa)　 → 　[particle-na](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-na)
　[に](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%e3%81%ab) 　→　 [particle-ni](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-ni)
　[の](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%e3%81%ae)　 →　 [particle-no](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-no)
　[は](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%e3%81%af) 　→　 [particle-wa](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-wa)
　[へ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%e3%81%b8) 　→　 [particle-e](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-e)
　[より](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%88%e3%82%8a) →　 [particle-yori](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-yori)
　[を](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%92) 　→ 　[particle-wo](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-wo)

There's no need to retag anything—we can add synonyms without bumping old questions.

Comment: You could also make a tag synonym for `より` and `ゟ`.